# Printing a PDF on a thermal label printer from Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf

We have just purchased a pretty stock standard thermal label printer, a usb TSC DC2700, to print courier labels. We have Ubuntu 19.10 running on our Lenovo PC (which has been awesome).

I have installed the driver, albeit for the TSC DA200 which is apparently the same printer and set the paper size etc.

Using the CUPS web interface I can print the Ubuntu test page, I can also print from Inkscape no problems.

I can not, for the life of me, print a PDF which is what we have to be able to do as that is what comes from the couriers web interface.

What happens is I open the PDf, hit print, the printer feeds out a label like it's printing but it ha no printing on it.

Help!

Comment: Look at `/var/log/cups/*`.

Comment: @waltinator - I've had a look but there isn't much. Trying to print to the printer doesn't append anything to the logs.

Comment: Ok - I CAN print the labels from the Chrome PDF viewer, but not from the document viewer that comes with Ubuntu. Interesting. I'll try some other viewers and see what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be, don't use the Document Viewer supplied with Ubuntu but print from the Chrome PDF viewer.